# GIT push command is very slow on CentOS, Apache

Tags: centos, git

I created GIT server on my CentOS with Apache. (push/pull are go trough http and Apache)

I followed those instructions: http://www.jedi.be/blog/2009/05/06/8-ways-to-share-your-git-repository/

Push command is very slow. Every time I push it takes more than 10s (even if I changed one line of code from last push).

Is this normal?

Size of repozitory is 150MB.

Operation which takes most of the time is:

> updating 'refs/heads/master'   from
>   00c9d81959fc020c9f273e7c2887af461a52e0cf   to
>   ccf47c31b7dcb32952f5251857660fa34018c5e1

What could be wrong?

Comment: Are you using Smart HTTP Transport ( http://progit.org/2010/03/04/smart-http.html ). If you are not sure, can you share the apache config. that deals with your Git repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebDAV is not particularly fast, although you might want to see about disk and CPU usage on your server.  My advice would be to create a brand new repository with nothing in it, and see how the speeds increase/decrease as you add commits, just to verify that its not a size issue (or a diff issue).